# How memory consumption works when passing large objects to functions

Tags: python, memory-management

I would like to understand how memory management works when an argument is passed to a function in Python.  The motivation for this question is that I am passing a dictionary with many keys to wrapper functions as my code progresses.  The wrapper functions take in some arguments and write new key-value pairs to the dictionary and return it.  I know it's best practice for functions to take in arguments that they use only.  But let's assume it's easier to keep passing this dictionary and adding to it for the sake of code readibility and docstring brevity.

Would like to understand the following.  When I pass this large dictionary to the function, is there more memory being consumed by this large dictionary as opposed to if I were to only pass the values that are used by the function?  In other words, does Python create a copy of the input argument, thus taking up more memory than necessary? If not, then if I were to only pass the necessary arguments, does Python still hold the dictionary as in memory so that we can work with it after we finish executing the particular function?

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. No copies are made, ever, when calling a function, because the parameter name is simply bound to whatever reference is passed as an argument.

Comment: So by that logic, whether I pass the full dictionary or only the specific key value pairs that I use, there shouldn't be a difference in terms of memory consumption?

Comment: Correct. The dict itself is just a collection of references to the values that exist separately from the dict. (Technically, using more parameters uses more memory, but we're talking about a small, fixed number of bytes per reference, not copies of objects.)